# Left shift operation

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

1. When I execute `j <<= 1` while `j` is initially zero, it ends up as a zero instead of 1 as it normally should be. Any other initial value is normally doubled.

   Does anyone know why this is happening?
2. Why bitwise operations on slice fields cause runtime errors?

Comment: An initial value of zero is also doubled: 2 * 0 = 0.

Comment: show what doesn't work for #2. Slice indexes are addressable.

Comment: @JimB try to apply a bitwise operation on a slice field and you will get an "index out of range" runtime error. I can't quite understand why this is happening so i would be pleased if someone could provide an explanation.

Comment: @mike: please show how you're doing this. It does work http://play.golang.org/p/UkiVBzyfGj

Comment: right, i was just not assigning a length to my slice

**slice := ([]int, 0, 5)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider `j = 0`:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Now what is `j <<= 1`? It's:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
←                 ↑
Shifted         Added
```

Which is.. the same number (0).

Left shifting a number by 1, is multiplying it by 2, 0*2 is 0.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Do you happen to know anything about my second question?

Comment: Actually I don't really understand it, I was answering your question before you edited it and added the second one. Will try to find an answer.

Comment: Tried using arrays instead of slices and it worked like a charm! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If `j` is zero, all of its bits are `0`. When you shift the bits one position to the left, they all remain as zero, and a new zero bit is added on the right. Therefore all the bits in the result are zero, and the result is zero.